# How to modify the number of logical CPUs used by a process?

Tags: go

> GOMAXPROCS sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing simultaneously and returns the previous setting. It defaults to the value of runtime.NumCPU.

> NumCPU returns the number of logical CPUs usable by the current process.

---

Below code does not change the number of logical CPUs used by a process:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumCPU()) // Expected: 1  Actual: 8
}
```

---

In my laptop:

```
$ lscpu # shows eight virtual cores corresponding to eight OS threads
...
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  4
    Socket(s):           1

$ go version
go version go1.20.2 linux/amd64
```

---

How to modify the logical CPU's used by the program?

Comment: If you want to limit the number of logical CPUs used by a process, you have to set the `GOMAXPROCS` variable to the desired value before running the program . `GOMAXPROCS=1 go run main.go`

Comment: @skshahriarahmedraka, no you can change GOMAXPROCS during runtime, the question is a misunderstanding of what GOMAXPROCS does

Answer (score 4):

If you were to read what docs has to say about [runtime.GOMAXPROCS](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#GOMAXPROCS) and [runtime.NumCPU()](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#NumCPU) you would see:

> func NumCPU
> [...]
>
> The set of available CPUs is checked by querying the operating system at process startup. **Changes to operating system CPU allocation after process startup are not reflected**.

"Changes to operating system CPU allocation after process startup are not reflected", this is why you don't see this value change.

Now lets see the GOMAXPROCS's docs

> func GOMAXPROCS [...]
>
> GOMAXPROCS sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing simultaneously and **returns the previous setting**. It defaults to the value of runtime.NumCPU. **If n < 1, it does not change the current setting**. This call will go away when the scheduler improves.

So you can check the currently set value by running:

```golang
fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
```

Comment: Note that `GOMAXPROCS` only affects threads with "user-level Go code". Running a go process with `GOMAXPROCS=1` can still use any number of OS threads for runtime processes. If you want to limit actual CPU cores, it must be done outside the process.

Comment: @JimB yes, when I say logical CPU, GOMAXPROCS set the number of process contexts (`P`) that go runtime can use. Each process context works with one OS thread(`M`). GOMAXPROCS has nothing to do with CPU core at OS level

Comment: So, Go scheduler will work with one process context, instead of 8

Answer (score 3):

There is no contradiction.

GOMAXPROCS affects the number of processes/threads that will be used by Go runtime. Exactly which CPU cores they will execute on will vary based on other load on the system.

NumCPU returns the number of cores available. It doesn't change even if Go runtime is configured not to take advantage of all of them.

NumCPU will reflect limits set through operating system mechanisms, e.g.

```
user@host:~$ go run test.go
4

user@host:~$ taskset -c 0 go run test.go
1
```